# Debugging Android Apps

Tags: android

Debugging in Eclipse works excellent, however, my app causes my whole system to crash on unknown interval in under unknown situations. I have never been able to replicate this issue while having a connection with my computer and thus I can't find the issue.

Are there any other ideas on how to approach this type of issues?

Comment: does your app crash, before it causes the entire system to crash?

Comment: nope, it makes the whole system crash.

Comment: yes, but I suppoe your app crashes first so @Paul-Jan answer may be a good start for you.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine used this [Bootlog Uptime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.mumu21.bootlog&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInNlLm11bXUyMS5ib290bG9nIl0.) app to get crash logs from system crashes.

I never tested it but as far as I know you can get the log from the system crash as well. At least worth a try...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your application crashes before it takes down the device, a generic error reporting solution like [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) (which you probably want as part of your application anyway) might get you the relevant bits of information to find the source of the problem (bits of the logcat, memory usage, etc).

If the app doesn't crash, you can set it up to periodically send out the same information. There might be a trend visible up to the point where it dies.